# How do I import JARs and Packages in Java

Tags: java, jar, package

I'm relatively new to Java. I've been using Eclipse to do some work but I want to get back to basics and just use a text editor in conjunction with the JDK. The problem I'm now having is that Eclipse and other IDEs hide away a lot of fundamental stuff which is very important to know and fully understand.  This is what I'm trying to do:

- I've created a directory called "C:\Java Projects", under which I have created 3 sub-folders, Project1, Project2 and SharedJars. Project1 and Project2 both have SubDirs like classes and source. The Poject1 source .java files live in "c:\Java Projects\Project1\source\com\myApp"
- Both Project1 and Project2 are packages which use the Log4J JAR which lives in the SharedJars folder.  In the Eclipse world, I could set something which told Eclipse which JARs my Project will use and then do something like import org.apache.log4j.Logger which worked fine.  But I'm struggling to get this working.
- I've set the CLASSPATH environment variable like **"C:\Java Projects\SharedJars\log4j-1.2.15.jar"**
- I then do the following:

  **cd Project1\source**
  **javac -d ..\classes com\myApp\***
- This produces a whole bunch of related errors like

*Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Duser.home="C:\Java Projects"

com\myApp\Monitor.java:11: cannot find symbol

symbol  : class Logger

location: class com.myApp.Monitor

        private static Logger LOG;*

Some questions:
1) Do i still need to import org.apache.log4j.Logger?
2) If so, what determines the FQDN of the package?
3) Do I need to be in a specific directory in order to run javac? Currently i'm going into the source directory of Project1 (the java/bin is in my PATH already)

Sorry for these silly questions.  I've trawled through so many websites but many do not cover the very basics. I hope this makes sense.

Rgds
John

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to SO.

In answer to this:

> Do i still need to import org.apache.log4j.Logger?

Yes you always need to use import directives any class you want to use. Java won't load anything even if it is on the classpath unless you tell it to.

> If so, what determines the FQDN of the package?

Inside the jar, the .class files are located in subdirectories like this: `org/apache/log4j ...` etc. This is how the FQDN is determined and it is used basically as a namespace construct so you can have two or more classes of the same name - which is also why Java can't load everything on the classpath. If it did, it would have no way to disambiguate and work out which class you wanted.

> Do I need to be in a specific directory in order to run `javac`?

No. You can run this from anywhere provided the classpath, from whereever you are, can get to your dependencies. It could be a relative classpath if specified on the command line or absolute if in an environment variable. Likewise you don't need to be in a specific directory to use `java` but you do need it to be able to get to the correct location.

Comment: Many thanks for your reponse. With help from finnw, I'm now setting the -classpath on the javac command explicity citing the log*jar which did the trick

Comment: Excellent, glad it's now working! I +1'd his answer for his efforts!

Comment: Java can load classes without using an import, you have to fully qualify them every time you use them and they have to be on the classpath, e.g. org.apache.log4j.Logger log = new org.apache.log4j.Logger();

Comment: @Kelly true. I did omit to mention that org.apache.log4j.Logger x = new org.apache.log4j.Logger() would work...

Answer (score 1):

> > 1) Do i still need to import org.apache.log4j.Logger?

Yes you do, and that should fix the error in your question, because your `CLASSPATH` is correct.

> > 2) If so, what determines the FQDN of the package?

The `import` does not change the FQDN of the package.  It just allows you to refer to `org.apache.log4j.Logger` simply as `Logger` within that file.

> > 3) Do I need to be in a specific directory in order to run javac?

No, but it's easiest if the current directory is the `source` directory of the project you are compiling (if it was not, you could work around it with the `-sourcepath` option to `javac`.)

As for running the program, you might want to create a `Project1.jar` and use the manifest to tell it where to find `log4j.jar`, but that's [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464205/java-manifest-files-class-path-and-how-it-determines-relative-dirs).

Comment: Ok so I add the line:  

import org.apache.log4j.Logger; 

It then comes back with this.....  "package org.apache.log4j does not exist"

Thanks for your reply

Comment: @John Wilkinson, It may be that you set the environment variable incorrectly.  Try moving the classpath to the command line, e.g. `javac -classpath "C:\Java Projects\SharedJars\log4j-1.2.15.jar" -d ..\classes com\myApp\Monitor.java` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: That's it!  I need to understand why my CLASSPATH var is not being evaluated correctly but that's another issue.  Many thanks to all reponses

Answer (score 0):

I post my solution because none of above solutions were suitable for me. It works for me under Windows XP/7.

#### SOLUTION

1. Download zip or tar package from log4j site[1] to your computer & unpack downloaded file.
2. Copy file log4j-VERSION.jar to your LOG4J_ISTALLATION_DIR (e.g. c:\javalibs\log4j-1.2.16.jar)
3. Open Properties of "My Computer/Computer" (icon should be placed on your desktop, just click right mouse button on it & choose Properties)
4. Open tab "Advanced System Settings".
5. Opend tab "Advanced"
6. Click on button "Environment variables".
7. Find variable CLASSPATH on "Environment variables" area, match it with left button and click "Edit" button.
8. Paste/type path to your log4j library - LOG4J_ISTALLATION_DIR\log4j-VERSION.jar; (e.g. c:\javalibs\log4j-1.2.16.jar;)
9. Click "OK" button.
10. Click "OK" button on "Environment variables" window.
11. Click "OK" button on "System Properties" window.
12. Go to command line and check if everything works by trying example from log4j short tutorial (attachede below):

    > cd c:\Users\User\log4j
    >   javac MyApp2.java
    >   2012-03-30  21:32               510 Bar.class
    >   2012-03-30  21:24               177 Bar.java
    >   2012-03-30  21:26               334 MyApp2-log4j.properties
    >   2012-03-30  21:32               916 MyApp2.class
    >   2012-03-30  21:25               775 MyApp2.java
    >   java MyApp2 MyApp2-log4j.properties
    >   0    [main] INFO  MyApp2 - Entering application
    >   2    [main] DEBUG Bar - Did it again
    >   3    [main] INFO  MyApp2 - Exiting application

#### CONTEXT: Prepare program that uses some *jar file [1] (problem source):

// 1. Go to your source directory (e.g. c:\Users\Hopbit\log4j )

// 2. Create below Bar class and save as Bar.java

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Bar {
  static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Bar.class);
  public void doIt() {
    logger.debug("Did it again!");
  }
}
```

// 3. Create below MyApp2 class and save as MyApp2.java

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class MyApp2 {

  static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyApp.class.getName());

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // BasicConfigurator replaced with PropertyConfigurator.
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(args[0]);

    logger.info("Entering application.");
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.doIt();
    logger.info("Exiting application.");
  }
}
```

// 4. Create & save MyApp2-log4j.properties file which contains below code:

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

// 5. Try to compile above example, it should return something like this:

```
> c:\Users\Hopbit\log4j>javac MyApp2.java
> MyApp2.java:1: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
> import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
>                         ^
> // [...] SOME OTHER ERRORS HERE
```

#### LINKS & HINTS

[1] http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html ("Short introduction to log4j: Ceki GŁlcŁ, March 2002")
[2] http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html
[3] Above solution was founded in file INSTALL that is placed uder log4j package.