# How to use *.jar file in a Java project?

Tags: java, jar

I'm a complete novice to Java, and I'm stuck in trying to use an external jar library in a Java project I'm working on.

The library is Twitter4J (http://twitter4j.org/), a complex group of files which I can't understand how to include. I'm using Eclipse on Windows. I understood the meaning of CLASSPATH enviroment variable (or well, I think I did), but I can't understand how to link it to the Eclipse enviroment.

This blog post seemed to be what I was looking for: http://jasperpeilee.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/how-to-set-up-twitter4j-quickly-in-your-java-project/

But:

```
Add twitter4j-core-2.2.5.jar into project for general use.
```

1) **Where** should I copy the `core` file? In the `/bin/` folder? Or in a completly unrelated `/lib/` folder, as *[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667494/how-do-i-import-jars-and-packages-in-java)* question in SO stated?

```
Copy Twitter API property file into your project/bin directory.
```

2) **What** is the Twitter API property file?

3) **How** can I include JavaDoc jar files too? Is it possibile to get them into Elipse?

Any kind of help, even just a link, will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably have a project folder for your Eclipse project. Go ahead and make a `lib` folder inside of your project folder, in the same directory as `src` and `bin`. There's nothing special about the `lib` folder specifically, it's just a convenient name. Copy the .jar file into your newly created folder. Back in Eclipse, right click your project and click `Refresh`. The `lib` folder should pop up, including your JAR! Right click the JAR file and go to Build Path --> Add To Build Path. At this point, any class in the project should be able to use Twitter4J features.

Comment: I successfully included the file in the project, and in fact `twitter4j-core-3.0.3-sources.jar` now is contained in in *Referenced libraries*, thanks to your useful advice. I linked it to its own javadoc archive too (thanks to @barry-nl). But, even if `twitter4j.*` gives no inclusion problem (but still its methods are unknown to my class), `twitter4j.Twitter` and everything else don't work properly: `The import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken cannot be resolved`, as if the library can be seen, but it's utterly empty. It looks weird (and a little bit frustrating)...

Comment: Hmm. Did multiple JAR files come with Twitter4J?

Comment: Yup, you can see them here: https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j. The one I included is "twitter4j-core". Anyway, following your method I was able to include some other libraries, such as `javax.mail`, so it's the right way ;)

Comment: Yep :D I'm glad it worked out! If there are multiple JAR files, you might need to include them in order for Twitter4J files to work correctly. (For example, Jetty, a Java webserver, has ~10 JAR files I think for various functionality.)

Answer (score 2):

As for the **What** question, the Twitter API property file contains configuration that is necessary for the Twitter jar to function. The file should probably be located on the classpath of your application.

And the **How** question, you can attach the javadoc jar file of the Twitter jar to the Twitter jar's classpath entry in Eclipse. Right-click your project and select Properties. Go to the Java Build Path entry and find the Twitter jar under the Libraries tab. If you expand the Twitter jar entry you will see 'JavaDoc location'. You can specify the javadoc jar there.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, right-click your project, select Properties. Now find the entry for Java Build Path and select it. Click the "Libraries" tab if it is not already selected. Click the "Add external JARs..." button. Follow the prompts.