# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver when executing JAR

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jar, classpath

I am attempting to connect to my local MySQL server with the following code:

```
dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306:/" + dbname;
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbuser, dbpass);
    } catch (SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("ERROR: Could not connection to SQL DB");
        con = null;
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("Error: ");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I then get

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I understand that Java cannot find the proper driver for connecting the Java environment to the MySQL database. This is being compiled on a Windows 7 system and ported over to an Ubuntu 11.04 system.

Is there a particular way I can run the Java program with a particular classpath such as:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar program.jar
```

That didn't work when I tried it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of JARs, the `-cp` and `-classpath` arguments and the `%CLASSPATH%` environment variable are **ignored**. Instead, the classpath has to be specified in the `Class-Path` entry of JAR's own `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file. It can be a path relative to the JAR itself. E.g. in the same folder or in a `/lib` subfolder.

The below example assumes the driver to be in the same folder as the JAR.

```
Class-Path: mysql-connector-java.jar
```

*(make sure that the `MANIFEST.MF` file has a blank line at the end)*

#### See also:

- [Using JAR files - The Basics - Understanding the MANIFEST.MF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)
- [Eclipse: Package multiple projects into one JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218506/eclipse-package-multiple-projects-into-one-jar/)
- [Java Manifest file's class path and how it determines relative dirs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464205/java-manifest-files-class-path-and-how-it-determines-relative-dirs/)

Answer (score 4):

Install MySQL connector for JAVA

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-java
```

Set classpath

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
```

Source: http://marksman.wordpress.com/2009/03/01/setting-up-mysqljdbc-driver-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

No matter where it's compiled, it will run smoothly in the same JVM implementation.

All you have to do is to properly include a JDBC driver connector in your classpath. Try putting mysql-connector-java.jar into the same directory with your program.

If you unzip this jar file, does it contain com/mysql/jdbc/Driver.class? If not, try to download jdbc driver implementation from the mysql web-site.

Comment: @Blackninja543 Also, as of JDBC 4.0 there is no need to load the driver in order to use it. The JDBC Specification section 9.2.1 explains how compatible drivers now support service provider mechanism. If your jdbc jar file contains META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file with the driver class, it means you need not to load the driver in order to use. You just need in your class path.