# Exporting jdbc in project jar file

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, manifest, manifest.mf

I have a JAVA program which connects to MySQL and performers some update tasks. I now want to export the application as a `jar` file with included JDBC package. I'm doing something like (**`pwd`** for all the following commands is: `/home/tnp/UpdateServer_SRC/bin/`):

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH 
.:/home/tnp/UpdateServer_SRC/bin/update/server:/home/tnp/UpdateServer_SRC/bin/update/server/jdbc.jar
$ java update.server.Main
Latest: 12177
IGNORING: 12172
IGNORING: 12173
IGNORING: 12174
IGNORING: 12175
IGNORING: 12176
IGNORING: 12177
^C
```

so far so goo, I'm quitting the execution as it performs them in a while loop every 30 minutes.

Now, creating the `jar` file:

```
$ jar cvf sth.jar update
added manifest
adding: update/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: update/server/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: update/server/ThreadNetwork.class(in = 1866) (out= 1021)(deflated 45%)
adding: update/server/HomePage.class(in = 2046) (out= 1184)(deflated 42%)
adding: update/server/jdbc.jar(in = 876733) (out= 837707)(deflated 4%)
adding: update/server/UpdateLast5.class(in = 2045) (out= 1179)(deflated 42%)
adding: update/server/Main.class(in = 742) (out= 504)(deflated 32%)
adding: update/server/Notice.class(in = 2715) (out= 1521)(deflated 43%)
```

Ok. Jar file created. Let's try to run it:

```
$ java -jar sth.jar 
no main manifest attribute, in sth.jar
```

Oh, the `pwd` is not in my current class path. Let me try again:

```
$ java -cp sth.jar update.server.Main
Latest: 12177
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at update.server.UpdateLast5.run(UpdateLast5.java:18)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at update.server.UpdateLast5.run(UpdateLast5.java:40)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

And this stacktrace is thrown. I saw on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8621249/1190388) that:

> In case of JARs, the `-cp` and `-classpath` arguments and the `%CLASSPATH%`
>   environment variable are ignored.

and I'd need to modify the `MANIFET.MF` file manually, and recreate the jar. But the answer linked above states that the class-path should be relative to my own jar file (`sth.jar`) and doesn't mention what to do about bundled jar files.

How do I import JDBC in my package so that the resulting jar file would function "normally". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use Eclipse? It can do this easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem currently by using the following MANIFEST file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_25 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: update.server.Main
Class-Path: jdbc.jar
```

and putting `jdbc.jar` in the same directory as my `sth.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

Include required JARs in your generated JAR root and load them at runtime (which means you need a `ClassLoader` to handle this).

Most IDEs do this for you, for example in Eclipse you just tell it to "Package required libraries in JAR".

*Ant* can also do so [as explained in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821803/creating-a-bundle-jar-with-ant).